# Postgresql left join date_trunc with default values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables which I'm querying to get the data based on different conditions. I have `from` and `to` params and these are the ones I'm using to create a range of time in which I'm looking for the data in those tables.

For instance if I have `from` equals to '2020-07-01' and `to` equals to '2020-08-01' I'm expecting to receive the grouped row values of the tables by week, if in some case some of the weeks don't have records I want to return 0, if some tables have records for the same week, I'd like to sum them.

Currently I have this:

```
SELECT d.day, COALESCE(t.total, 0)
FROM  (
  SELECT day::date
  FROM generate_series(timestamp '2020-07-01',
                       timestamp '2020-08-01',
                       interval  '1 week') day
) d
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT date AS day,
         SUM(total)
  FROM table1
  WHERE id = '1'
  AND date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-08-01'
  GROUP  BY day
) t USING (day)
ORDER BY d.day;
```

I'm generating a series of dates grouped by week, and on top of that I'm doing adding a left join. Now for some reason, it only works if the dates match completely, otherwise `COALESCE(t.total, 0)` returns 0 even if in that week the SUM(total) is not 0.

The same way I'm applying the LEFT JOIN, I'm using other left joins with other tables in the same query, so I'm falling with the same problem.

Comment: Are your weeks supposed to begin on whatever day is the first day of the month?  In your example, it looks like your weeks run from Wednesday to Tuesday whereas August will run from Saturday to Sunday.

Comment: Thanks Mike, the range of time (the weeks) are supposed to be generated dynamically depending on the from and to values, both values are the same for the FROM and LEFT JOIN clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see if this works for you.  Whenever you find yourself aggregating more than once, ask yourself whether it is necessary.

Rather than try to match on discrete days, use time ranges.

```
with limits as (
  select '2020-07-01'::timestamp as dt_start, 
         '2020-08-01'::timestamp as dt_end
), weeks as (
  SELECT x.day::date as day, least(x.day::date + 7, dt_end::date) as day_end
    FROM limits l
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
           generate_series(l.dt_start, l.dt_end, interval '1 week') as x(day)
   WHERE x.day::date != least(x.day::date + 7, dt_end::date)
), t1 as (
  select w.day, 
         sum(coalesce(t.total, 0)) as t1total
    from weeks w
         left join table1 t
                on t.id = 1
               and t.date >= w.day 
               and t.date < w.day_end
   group by w.day
), t2 as (
  select w.day, 
         sum(coalesce(t.sum_measure, 0)) as t2total
    from weeks w
         left join table2 t
                on t.something = 'whatever'
               and t.date >= w.day 
               and t.date < w.day_end
   group by w.day
)
select t1.day,
       t1.t1total,
       t2.t2total
  from t1
  join t2 on t2.day = t1.day;
```

You can keep adding tables like that with CTEs.

My earlier example with multiple `left join` was bad because it blows out the rows due to a lack of join conditions between the left-joined tables.

There is an interesting corner case for e.g. `2019-02-01` to `2019-03-01` which returns an empty interval as the last week. I have updated to filter that out.

Comment: @KarolKarol  In case you want to get stuff from multiple tables in a single query, I have updated the example to show how to add other tables to this query.

Comment: This solves the problem thanks a lot, just  a quick question why do you use >= and < and not between? Also the last day I'm receiving is 2020-07-29, does that would take into account the records for 2020-07-30, 2020-07-31?

Comment: @KarolKarol  Between is inclusive at both ends.  This means that your date parms would include records from `2020-08-01` in the results.  If that is what you want, then you can switch back to `between`.  This query includes 07-29 through 07-31 in the entry for 07/29 but it does not include records from 08-01 and later.

Comment: @KarolKarol  Sorry, but my multiple table example was bad and I removed it.  That needs to be done with CTEs.  Please let me know if you need to see it with CTEs.

Comment: I tested it and worked @Mike, anyway if you can update your answer I'd be grateful.

Comment: @KarolKarol  Answer is updated along with an explanation of why it was wrong.  I have to drink more water, I think.